# Does Environment Canada offer archived radar data in gridded format like in the US?

Tags: meteorology, radar

I have seen social media-rologists (weather weenies on Twitter) using the Weatherscope app to [display data from the Canadian radar network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlj5a.jpg), which was recently upgraded to dual-pol. For many years, NCEI has archived NEXRAD data in GRIB2 format and made it freely accessible to the public. It can be visualized on a computer using the [Weather and Climate Toolkit](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/wct/), or WCT. Does Environment Canada offer the same kind of archived radar data that NCEI does to the public? If not, how does Radarscope gain access to it?

Comment: I've never used WeatherScope's pro tier (only just recently added WS for when traveling), so have no familiarity myself... are you sure the archive they offer isn't just covering the period roughly since they've been offering live data, so the archive is their own rather than from Environment Canada?  As to where they get the current gridded data, I don't know that either, though it's not what you're asking... but if you do know where, might be good to include in the question for everyone's benefit :)